# Range() Auto-Capitalization in Editor

Tags: vba

When I first began using Excel VBA my range identifiers would always auto-capitalize but that is no longer the case

Originally, I could type `range("a1")` and the VBA editor would correct it to `Range("A1")`.

Now I type `range("a1")` and the VBA editor corrects it to `Range("a1")`.

I am looking to see if there is some tool that will allow that functionality back to capitalize the letter `A`. Seems to have started after I added the Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library in order to try some Word VBA.

Comment: VBA Doesn't capitalize the Letters written between `""`. It will surely do it for the `r` of range, because that is an Object. Also it doesn't matter if you write `a1` or `A1` , the range will refer to the same cell without error.

Comment: I have been using VBA for years and have never seen "a1" auto-corrected to "A1"

Comment: Appreciate the formatting on my question, first time asking. I guess a follow-up question would be: Is is best practice to capitalize the letter to avoid confusion? I have been using VBA part time for about a year now but no one else really reads my work extensively, I just do some process improvement for my team

Comment: Why would you add `Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library` to perform VBA on Word Object model? Use `Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library` directly.

Comment: @knights - There is no confusion between `Range("A1")` and `Range("a1")`, They are the same. Stylistically, I would choose one way for the entire code base, otherwise it's jarring to the eye.

Comment: Thanks for the input! @ScottHoltzman I do not remember why I specifically selected the Office library instead of Word, I think the IT guy at work may have directed me to do that.